# Show data between two dates by using a phone number using Hasura Graphql

Tags: hasura

I am using the following query to fetch data from two specific date
by using a phone number.

Here the 3 arguments are : dateFrom, dateTo, phoneNumber

```
query MyQuerylT($dateFrom : timestamp!, $dateTo : timestamp!, $phoneNumber : String! ) {
  tracking(

  where: {
  
    {place_time: {_gte: $dateFrom}}, {place_time: {_lte: $dateTo}},
    {phone_number : $phoneNumber}
  
    
  }){
    phone_number
    place_time
    name
    address
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
query MyQuerylT($dateFrom : timestamp!, $dateTo : timestamp!, $phoneNumber : String! ) {
  tracking(
     where: {_and: [{place_time: {_gt: $dateFrom}}, {place_time: {_lte: $dateTo}}, {phoneNumber: {_eq : $phoneNumber} }]}

 ){
    phone_number
    place_time
    name
    address
  }
}
```